# NPM errors when running npm run compile

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-run

When I run npm run comile:js, I get this problem. So what to do?

```
PS C:\Users\Marko\Desktop\storefrontdata-master\storefrontdata-master> npm run compile:js
npm ERR! missing script: compile:js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Marko\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-04T11_00_45_777Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Marko\Desktop\storefrontdata-master\storefrontdata-master>
```

This is how my package.json looks, if you can if it is ok:

```
{
  "name": "refarchdata",
  "version": "4.4.1",
  "description": "This is a repository for the data that goes with the ref arch storefront.",
  "main": "",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "zipData": "if [ -f demo_data_sfra.zip ] ; then rm -r demo_data_sfra.zip && zip -r demo_data_sfra.zip demo_data_sfra ; else zip -r demo_data_sfra.zip demo_data_sfra ; fi"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/storefrontdata.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/storefrontdata"
}
```

Comment: check the folder path is correct. is the files inside `C:\Users\Marko\Desktop\storefrontdata-master`?

Comment: @MatJ I changed path, but I got now this: PS C:\Users\Marko\Desktop\storefrontdata-master\storefrontdata-master> npm run compile:js
npm ERR! missing script: compile:js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Marko\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-04T11_00_45_777Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Marko\Desktop\storefrontdata-master\storefrontdata-master>

Answer (score 0):

the error told you the reason already:

```
no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Marko\Desktop\storefrontdata-master\package.json'
```

your project do not have `package.json` file. Please make sure you have one.

update following your update: open package.json (if has), then look for `scripts` and make sure compile:js is under it. The file should look like this:

```
// package.json
 {
  .....
 scripts : {
     "compile:js": "....",
 }
  ....

 }
```

Comment: I changed path, so if you can see in question now what I got when I run compile..

Comment: I updated my answer. And you also found yours if read the meaning of error log they throw first.

Comment: Thanks. If you can see my package.json file, I added in question

Comment: As I said above, under `scripts` are all commands that you are be able to run. In your package.json, `zipData` is the only command you can run `npm run zipData` @markk

Answer (score 0):

you should add a script in the file package.json to be able to run the
as this shape
npm run compile
it will be check if that has a script in the package.json  then it will be run it
like this

```
{
  //some code
 scripts : {
     "compile:js": "waht you need to put here",
 }
 

 }
```

if you want to run the file his name compile.js  used node with the location of the file
like that  `node compile.js`